# Average of orders placed by an user

Tags: reporting, formula-field, roll-up-summary

I have a requirement where I need to get the average number of Users who are placing orders each month. If I get the count using Roll up summary field, it will be the copmplete count of the year and I cannot get exact figure per month. If I do roll up summary per month, there will be around 12 fields. How to get this report. Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: You can do this in a report directly without formulas. Have you tried building the report?

Comment: Yes...Thanks @sfdcfox for your concern over this question...Now I have total count of Users placing orders each month. Like 5,59,695 Users for Jan, 6,98,887 for Feb. How to get the average per month from this count?

Comment: You can use [Report Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=building_custom_summary_formulas.htm&type=5) to get things like average values. You would need to group your report by user and by month to get average per user per month.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a kind of trend analysis, better to think of implementing [Report on Historical Data with Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&type=5)

> A reporting snapshot lets you report on historical data. Authorized users can save tabular or summary report results to fields on a custom object, then map those fields to corresponding fields on a target object. They can then schedule when to run the report to load the custom object's fields with the report's data. Reporting snapshots enable you to work with report data similarly to how you work with other records in Salesforce.